# getting null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, function, nullpointerexception, textview

I am getting a NullPointerException when I try to access text view which is defined in view class. I am accessing it from setting class. A small part of my code is:

**view class**

```
public class view1 extends menu {
    public static TextView text1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view);
        text1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textfile1);
        text1.setText("product");
    }

    public void small(String mytext) { // this is my method which I want to access
        text1.setText(mytext);
    }
}
```

**setting class**

```
public class Setting extends Activity {


    private Spinner spinner1;
      private Button apply;
      TextView small1;
      private view1 view11;




      @Override


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.setting);
        //setContentView(R.layout.view);

        addItemsOnSpinner1();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();



}

    public void addItemsOnSpinner1() {

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Small");
        list.add("Medium");
        list.add("Large");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
      }

    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        apply = (Button) findViewById(R.id.apply);
        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());


        apply.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                  String mytext = "Something else";
                  view11.small(mytext);





                  }
```

Stack trace

```
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at com.ramanrayat.notelet.Setting$1.onClick(Setting.java:106)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-17 00:11:02.064: E/AndroidRuntime(4191):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

setting.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="Setting"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Font Size"
        android:textSize="30dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/apply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="Apply" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: in settings class where is view1 declared?

Comment: Can you please post the error log from LogCat?

Comment: is menu a base activity class?

Comment: Your Setting class extends an Activity I assume.

Comment: also is spinner1 initialized in settings class. pls post more code along with stacktrace

Comment: i post stack trace with some more code in my setting class

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yes bro it extend activity

Comment: change private view1 view11; to private View1 view11;

Comment: Please post the setting.xml file which should be located in your res/layout/ folder. If that file doesn't exist, then it probably means you got the concept of a Layout/View and an Activity confused, and you need to watch some of the youtube videos that talk about the fundamental building blocks of android before you go much further.

Comment: i created xml file already wait i am posting it ...

Comment: @StephanBranczyk i post setting.xml file also ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chnage

```
 if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem())=="Small")
```

TO

```
if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()).equals("Small"))
```

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings

Instead of making textview static you should use intents to pass values between activities.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityName.this,Settings.class);
intent.putExtra("key",text1.getText().toString());
startActivity(intent);
```

Then

```
String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

Change

```
  public static TextView text1;
```

to

```
   public TextView text1;
```

Also follow java naming conventions

Comment: i did changes but there is still null pointer exception error .

Comment: @ramanrayat post the stacktrace for further help. also post more relevant code.

Comment: actully i don't want to display text ... i am creating a notepad application in which i have setting class and i want to change font size of text view which is present in view1 class .

Comment: then you pass the size choosen by the user from setttings class to your view1 class using intent and change the font size. pls post the logcat

Comment: line 106 : view11.small(mytext);

in this i am calling a method define in my view1 class which change text

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45425/discussion-between-raman-rayat-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public static TextView text1;
```

with

```
TextView text1;
```

text1 can not be static.

Next time, please click on the file name in the error log and indicate which line number in your code listing is the line that the error actually points to.

Learn to start all your class names with capital letters (athough, this is not what's causing the problem). And while I'm at it, please stop using numbers in class names and in variables, especially the number 1, which can be ambiguously read as an "l" in some fonts.

Comment: thank you i did it but i am still getting error of null pointer exception

Comment: Also "public class view1 extends menu {" should be giving you a classNoFoundException. Menu should start with a capital letter, otherwise it won't be found. While you change that, don't forget to capitalize view1 as well. And finally, don't forget to organize your imports. Since menu was wrong, the new Menu most likely doesn't have the right import yet.

Comment: Please specify the line number (the number after the : of any error remaining), but since a line number won't tell us anything since StackOverflow doesn't give your line numbers to us, don't forget to mark the error where the line is with a // commment indicating such in your posted code.

Comment: line 106 : view11.small(mytext); in this i am calling a method define in my view1 class which change text

Comment: Correct the capitalization of View1 in the original file and when you initialize view11. This may actually be what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Look for your LogCat, it will told you where is NPE.
The other question is : don't use equals to compare String instead of ==

== is compare two object's address and equals is compare their value.

```
 if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()).equals("Small")) {
     String mytext = "Something else ";
     view11.small(mytext); // view11 is clas view1 reference
 }
 else if(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()).equals("Medium")) {
     finish();
 }
```

Comment: i did changes to == but still there is error when i try to call my method small();

Comment: at com.ramanrayat.notelet.Setting$1.onClick(Setting.java:106) check line 106 and fix it

Comment: line 106 : view11.small(mytext); in this i am calling a method define in my view1 class which change text ....